# react js pagination default sort

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

i have a table  that displays ***# Name Points Alliance Status*** the "#" is by numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 but right now is not organized, so it shows lets say 6,3,1,5,2,4 how can i default sort my table to be organized by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10etc...

***NOTE***: The data Fetched is fetched by an online API

***MY CODE***

````
    <>
      <div className="container-fluid mt-5 mb-5">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-md-10">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-body p-0">

                <div className="table-filter-info">

                  <Pagination
                    className="pagination-data"
                    showTotal={(total, range) => `Showing ${range[0]}-${range[1]} of ${total}`}
                    onChange={PaginationChange}
                    total={100}
                    current={current}
                    pageSize={size}
                    showSizeChanger={false}
                    itemRender={PrevNextArrow}
                    onShowSizeChange={PerPageChange}
                   
                    
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="table-responsive">
                  <table className="table table-text-small mb-0">
                    <thead className="thead-primary table-sorting">
                      <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Points</th>
                        <th>Alliance</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {
                    getData(current, size).map((name) => {
                        return (
                          <tr key={name.name}>
                            <td>{name.position}</td>
                            <td>{name.name}</td>
                            <td>{name.score}</td>
                            <td>{name.alliances}</td>
                            <td>{name.status}</td>
                          </tr>
                        )
                      })}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div className="table-filter-info">

                  <Pagination
                    className="pagination-data"
                    showTotal={(total, range) => `Showing ${range[0]}-${range[1]} of ${total}`}
                    onChange={PaginationChange}
                    total={100}
                    current={current}
                    pageSize={size}
                    showSizeChanger={false}
                    itemRender={PrevNextArrow}
                    onShowSizeChange={PerPageChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}```
````